# CSS animation delay behaves differently in Chrome than in IE/Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, animation, delay

I'm having some issues when using a delay with CSS animation.

My desired effect in the example:

*The red box **starts transparent** waits 1 second, then fades in.*

This happens in Chrome.

However, the behaviour in IE and Firefox is different:

*The box **starts visible**, waits 1 second, then disappears and fades back in.*

Which behaviour is correct? It seems to me that if you're going to delay an animation, it makes sense to wait at the first frame of the animation, not the last frame.

Is there a workaround without Javascript?

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }

 100% {
  opacity: 1; 
 }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }

 100% {
  opacity: 1; 
 }
}

.box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Declare `opacity: 0;` as the default style for `.box`

Comment: @ZachSaucier This makes the box disappear after the animation has run.

Comment: Have you checked animation fill mode? You could use the above `opacity: 0;` and fill mode of forwards to retain the applied effects after animating. (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp)

Comment: @somethinghere that fixed it! Post it as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks. :)

Comment: @AlexKempton (I didn't down vote and find this actually a pretty good question. Animation fill mode is not very known but useful and it took me a while to find out as well. Have added an answer and a link to MDN explaining it better than W3Schools.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use animation-fill-mode to determine how to 'fill' your animation when it ends. You can revert it to before, after, initial, etc... Its not the most intuitive naming convention, but it does allow you to set your animation to start with `opacity : 0;` and then retain the computed value you want after the animation using `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`.

MDN has a good explanation for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Comment: Great answer! One point to make is that using something like `opacity: 0` is dangerous without Modernizr to check for support, don't want all your content invisible!

Comment: Coming back to this after the weekend, it seems a lot more sensible not to set the `opacity` as a property but instead use `animation-fill-mode: both`, which makes it start with the opening keyframe during the delay, and retain the final keyframe once the animation has ended.

Comment: True. Told you the naming convention wasn't really obvious, but once you understand what they mean this kind of thing makes sense.